# how do i change a var value in jquery event handler wrapped in a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function canvasPlug(tab, curvesArg) {

  $('#gp_grid').change( function (e) {   
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    console.log(tab);
  });
}

$('#shapeButton').click(canvasPlug('shape'));
$('#profileButton').click(canvasPlug('profile'));
```

The first call logs 'shape'.
The second call logs 'shape' and 'profile' like it is being called twice.
I want to call the click event each time with a new value for the same var.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is every time you call `canvasPlug`, you are adding a new event handler to the `gp_grid` element.

Since you want only the latest value, you can remove the previously registered handlers using [.off()](https://api.jquery.com/off) - in the below snippet, name spaces are used to make sure that none of the other event handlers are removed by mistake.

```js
$('#shapeButton').click(function() {
  canvasPlug('shape')
});
$('#profileButton').click(function() {
  canvasPlug('profile')
});

function canvasPlug(tab, curvesArg) {
  $('#gp_grid').off('change.canvasPlug').on('change.canvasPlug', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    snippet.log(tab);
  });
}
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="shapeButton">shapeButton</button>
<button id="profileButton">profileButton</button>
<input id="gp_grid" />
```

Comment: Thank you, I should have asked hours ago. I had stacked handlers causing all kinds of confusion.

Comment: @Gordon also the way you are adding the click handlers are wrong